# need query for below output format

Tags: mysql

i have using table name smart_temp.checker.

This table contains below results:

```
select * from smart_temp.checker
```

**Table**

```
account-number    type_of_approver  status    remarks
11                     chck1        ok        approved
11                      chk2        ok        approved
12                      chck1       reject    mismatch
12                      chck1       ok        approved
12                      chck2       ok        approved
13                      chk1        reject    mismatch
13                      chk1        reject    mismatch
13                      chk1        ok        approved
13                      chk2        reject    address not clear
13                      chk2        ok        approved
14                      chk1        reject    mismatch
14                      chk2        reject    mismatch
```

Now my output is display below this format

```
 no of accounts   : 
 ok without reject :   
 ok after one reject :
 ok after two reject:
 rejected not processed again:
```

Now how to write query for this condition.i have tired wrote query i cannot get any idea how to write about this condition

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: have tried case statement but i cannot get clear idea..how to work on that...